# Return to Fragment A from Fragment B with a value

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I know there have been many threads about this, but i just cant seem to really understand how to nail it.. What i basically try to do is after button click in Fragment B i want to return to Fragment A together with a id value..

So in my BackStack you go to Fragment A which lead you to Fragment B and when pressing a button i want to go back to Fragment A with a value to show. This is my onClick listener in Fragment B:

```
//Fragment B which i called from Fragment A
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(value.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                 String order = value.getText().toString(); //The value i want in Fragment B
                 //return to Fragment A
            }
}
```

In my MainActivity i tread my fragment like this:

```
//fragmentManager is initialized in onCreate()
...
private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    String fTag = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentA();
            fTag = "fragmentA";
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentC();
            fTag = "fragmentC";
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentD();
            fTag = "fragmentD";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        if(replaceFragments(fragment, fTag)) {
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

public boolean replaceFragments(Fragment fragment, String fTag) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fTag).addToBackStack(fTag).commit();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        //TODO: add app title on count == 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onclick method should look like this:

```
 @Override 
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(value.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) { 
             String order = value.getText().toString(); //The value i want in Fragment B
             //return to Fragment A 

            FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
            Bundle args=new Bundle();
            args.putString(order);
           fragment.setArguments(args);
           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace((R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();


        }
```

And then from your FragmentA you can recover the value with:

```
getArguments();
```

Comment: Aha of course! Dont know why i didnt think of that.. Why is the interface method so common when you can set args like that?

Comment: With the interface you can send the value to your activity. If that's not what your looking for, then you can send your values straight to another fragment by using the above way.

Comment: Since fragmentManager lives inside the activity i guess i goes that way anyway? But i actually saw somewhere that it was not recommended to send directly between fragments?

Comment: On a quick read, you may be onto something: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html Although it never says why....maybe someone else can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

Create interface ValueChangeListener.java

```
public interface ValueChangeListener {

    public void onValueChanged(String value);
}
```

Pass the value via interface:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    private ValueChangeListener valueChangeListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            valueChangeListener = (ValueChangeListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement ValueChangeListener");
        }
    }

    //your code
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(value.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                 String order = value.getText().toString();
                 //now the value is in the Activity and you can pass it anywhere you want from there
                 valueChangeListener.onValueChanged(order);
            }
    }

}
```

Implement interface to the activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ValueChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onValueChanged(String value) {
    //your value is here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes sense. Can you tell me how i would call Fragment A the right way when i receive the value in the Activity?I mean it would be best to call it from the BackStack/get it from the tag?